# Not able to submit arguments with values within single quote to flink job

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to submit my jar with args.
I am using flink Rest Api to send my args in json format. 
My input sample in java is

```html
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 json.put("programArgs","--bootstrap.server \"localhost:9092\" --zookeeper.server \"localhost:2181\" --query \"where agentHost='192.168.170.111'\" --source.topic \"demo1\" --dest.topic \"rules\" --job.id \"123\" --extra.info \"sdcdscsd\"");
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toJSONString()));
```

when I give exactly these args my job runs via IDE, however when I send it via rest api my query arg comes without the single quotes. And hence I am getting Calcite sql parse exception.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the ' with unicode for the character: \u0027?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that... it doesnt works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the parameters as a list of parameters instead of as a string. You can do this by setting the `programArgsList` field instead which is of type array:

```
json.put("programArgsList", Arrays.asList("--bootstrap.server", "localhost:9092", "--zookeeper.server", "localhost:2181", "--query", "where agentHost='192.168.170.111'", "--source.topic", "demo1", ...));
```

That way Flink won't remove the single quotes as part of the input parsing. See [FLINK-10295](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10295) for more information.

Comment: What is the proper way of adding program arguments with UI? I tried some alternatives but none worked.